# Return count of items deleted using Get-ChildItem with Remove-Item

Tags: powershell

I am successfully deleting files as expected using the below command; however, I'd like to get a count of the items deleted.

```
Get-ChildItem $dPath -Filter "*.blah" | Remove-Item
```

I've tried this. It always deletes the file but the Measure-Object runs after the delete so 0 is always returned as the count

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -Filter "*.blah" | Remove-Item | Measure-Object
```

I've then tried it in reverse but always get:

> [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -Filter "*.blah" | Measure-Object | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collect the items in a variable, get the count of that list, then remove the items:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -Filter "*.blah"
$cnt   = $items.Count
$items | Remove-Item
```

or count the items that were successfully deleted:

```
$cnt = 0
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -Filter "*.blah" | ForEach-Object {
  Remove-Item $_.FullName
  if ($?) { $cnt++ }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write the `FileInfo` returned by `Get-ChildItem` to the output pipeline after deleting them:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path | 
   ForEach-Object { Remove-Item $_; Write-Output $_} | 
   Measure-Object
```

Comment: Thanks @heldi_! I liked yours but wound up using Ansgar's top example rather than do a loop.